# A unique item selected for each combobox C# MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, combobox

I really don't know how to do what I want. So I came here to ask you.

On my window, I have 6 `ComboBox`.
If I select an item (displayed item1 for example) in a `ComboBox`, I want to disable this `item1` for each others.
If I dropdown a second `ComboBox`, I can't select select `item1` and chose `item2`.
In a third `ComboBox`, it will not possible to select `item1` and `item2`. Etc ...

I use WPF with MVVM.

Could you help me please ?

**EDIT**

I've implement the solution of Ed Plunkett :
My converter :
I take the string of the item and a list of string which contain selected items

```
class ComboBoxItemDisableConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0].Equals(""))
        {
            return false;
        }

        bool contains = !(values[1] as List<string>).Contains(values[0].ToString());
        return contains;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I will not show you all the `xaml` file but only the important code :
All `ComboBox` are the same.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:ComboBoxItemDisableConverter x:Key="comboBoxItemDisableConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListeComposants}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemPrimaire00}">
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource comboBoxItemDisableConverter}">
                            <Binding />
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.SelectedItemsVuePrimaire"
                                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>
```

There is no code behind.
In my ViewModel, I put `SelectedItem` in a `List<string>` named ``

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private List<string> _selectedItemsVuePrimaire = new List<string> { "", "", "", "", "", "" };

    public List<string> ListeComposants { get; set; }

    public List<string> SelectedItemsVuePrimaire
    {
        get { return _selectedItemsVuePrimaire; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItemsVuePrimaire = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItemsVuePrimaire)));
        }
    }

    private string _selectedItemPrimaire00;

    public string SelectedItemPrimaire00
    {
        get { return _selectedItemPrimaire00; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItemPrimaire00 = value;
            SelectedItemsVuePrimaire[0] = _selectedItemPrimaire00;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItemPrimaire00)));
        }
    }

    private string _selectedItemPrimaire01;

    public string SelectedItemPrimaire01
    {
        get { return _selectedItemPrimaire01; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItemPrimaire01 = value;
            SelectedItemsVuePrimaire[1] = _selectedItemPrimaire01;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItemPrimaire01)));
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ListeComposants = new List<string>();
        ListeComposants.Add("");
        ListeComposants.Add("Dernières commandes");
        ListeComposants.Add("Fournisseurs");
        ListeComposants.Add("Relevé de prix");
        ListeComposants.Add("Remises financières");
        ListeComposants.Add("Historique E/S x mois");
        ListeComposants.Add("Prévisions");
        ListeComposants.Add("Equivalences");
        ListeComposants.Add("Caractéristiques");
        ListeComposants.Add("UG");
    }
```

For each first dropdowlist open, the dropdown list call the converter but if I open the dropdown for the second time, the converter is not call ...

**SOLUTION**

I add a PropertyChanged of my list of selectedItems when a selectedItem changed

```
    private string _selectedItemPrimaire00;

    public string SelectedItemPrimaire00
    {
        get { return _selectedItemPrimaire00; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItemPrimaire00 = value;
            SelectedItemsVuePrimaire[0] = _selectedItemPrimaire00;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItemsVuePrimaire)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedItemPrimaire00)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add checking on item select to check if it is selected in the other comboboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the viewmodel a property that is a collection of all the selected items. We'll call it `SelectedItems`. Update `SelectedItems` as the selections change, and raise `PropertyChanged` for that collection property. Each selection needs to be bound to a viewmodel property.

Give each ComboBox an ItemContainerTemplate with a DataTrigger.

Give the DataTrigger a multibinding that includes `<Binding/>` and `<Binding DataContext.SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" />`. Give the multibinding a multi-value converter (`IMultiValueConverter`) that returns `true` if `values[0]` (`<Binding/>`) is contained in `values[1]` (`SelectedItems`).

If the multi-value converter returns true, the trigger fires and sets `IsEnabled` to `False`.

Comment: If I use a MultiBinding in DataTigger, I have an error "Cannot use 'MultiBinding' in a 'SetterBaseCollection' collection."

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found the solution ! :D